# Codeigniter profiler execution time wrong?

Tags: codeigniter, profiler

I'm new to Codeigniter. I have installed CI 2.1.3 few days ago on WAMP (PHP 5.4.3).
I created my basic layout and enabled profiler.

When profiler is enabled it gives me next execution times:

Loading Time: Base Classes      **0.0228**
Controller Execution Time ( Layout / Index )    **0.0239**
Total Execution Time    **0.0468**

I decided to include in the view file next to see how accurate profiler is:

$time = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];
echo $time;

The output of the above is: **0.064446926116943**

Now it is definitely not equal to CI Profiler.

Am I missing something? Is CI Profiler accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CI Profiler doesn't actually does the measuring, its the benchmark-libary that does.  It measures each benchmark by getting a timestamp by using `microtime()` when a mark is added.  The profiler then calculates the difference between start and end-marks.

The difference will be because of initialisationtime before the first benchmark is set.

You can see where in the sourcecode where the first benchmarks get started.  It's in the file *system/core/codeigniter.php* at line 108:

```
$BM =& load_class('Benchmark', 'core');
$BM->mark('total_execution_time_start');
$BM->mark('loading_time:_base_classes_start');
```

Of course there were allready files loaded before that code is ran, so that's where the difference comes from.

Comment: So does this mean that the initialisation time will be always the same as Benchmark class is loaded on a certain offset?

Comment: I would say so unless the server is under stress or something that causes the code to run slower